# Why VGA Ubuntu in my Virtual Machine not same as my VGA PC?

Tags: virtualization, vmware, vga

I try to find out what is my graphic card by

```
lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12
```

and it shows that `VGA compatible controllers` is `SVGA VMware`

Comment: Quite correct. VMWare virtualizes hardware. That's the purpose of the product. One of the advantages is that the driver in the guest doesn't have to change if you move it to different hardware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple: VMware (or any other virtualization software) does normally not grant the VM direct access to the host's hardware, unless you specifically set it up that way.

Instead all hardware the VM sees is emulated, like the `SVGA VMware` you noticed. This is not a real, physical graphics card, but the hypervisor (here VMware) creates a virtual device that is accessible from inside the VM like a real graphics card.

If your VM must have direct access to your graphics hardware, search for "VMware GPU passthrough" and your graphics chip model.